# PyCharm can't find Tesseract on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycharm, tesseract

I'm starting out with some basic python tutorials with OpenCV, and the first tutorial uses Tesseract, Pytesseract, and OpenCV. I have Tesseract downloaded and pip installed, and I have Pytesseract and OpenCV downloaded, installed, and included in my PyCharm packages, so I think the problem is how I'm addressing the Tesseract file in my code, since I'm new to using a Mac.
(I'm using Python 3.8, but also have Python 2.7 installed, because I needed it to get to this point. Weirdly enough, up to this point, the code only ran without error if I had Python 2.7 installed, but had 3.8 as my PyCharm interpreter.)

When I put Tesseract into my terminal, it tells me that the file address is simply 'Applications/tesseract'. But when I use this as the address in PyCharm, I get the error message below. If anyone could help me figure out how to handle this error, I would appreciate it a lot!!! (I'm new to everything computers, btw. This is how I'm learning.)

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/george/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
  File "/Users/george/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 370, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "/Users/george/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/Users/george/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 282, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/george/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 254, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: \Applications\tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information."
```

I don't know what to look for in the README file, though.

Here is the code that kicked off the error message:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '\\Applications\\tesseract'
img = cv2.imread('im1.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
cv2.imshow('Result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Macs (and other Unix-like OSes), the path separator is the forward slash, not the backslash.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/Applications/tesseract'
```

could work better.

However, do you actually need to explicitly set that? It's likely the library could be able to find Tesseract on its own

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! The tutorial is from a Windows-user; I would never have caught that. (also thank you for editing the error code formatting!!).

Comment: I'm not sure if I do need to or not. The original error message (obviously) went away, but now there's an 'EOL while scanning string literal'. If I don't explicitly state that, then it says it can't find it again, like the original error message.